# Django rest related model not included

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a TwitchChannel model which has a ForeignKey relationship to CustomUser.

```
class TwitchChannel(models.Model):
    login = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    twitch_user_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    profile_image_url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    access_token = models.CharField(default="none", max_length=100)
    refresh_token = models.CharField(default="none", max_length=100)
    live = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    channel_data = JSONField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        make_password(self.access_token)
        make_password(self.refresh_token)
        super().save(**kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.display_name

    def get_channel_url(self):
        return f"https://twitch.tv/{self.login}"
```

In my **UserSerializer** I want to include this TwitchChannel when it exists. The following are my serializers.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    twitch_channel = TwitchChannelSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = UserModel.objects.create(
            email=validated_data["email"],
            first_name=validated_data["first_name"],
            last_name=validated_data["last_name"]
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data["password"])
        user.save()
        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        if 'password' in validated_data:
            password = validated_data.pop('password')
            instance.set_password(password)

    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        depth = 3
        fields = ( "id", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "password", "twitch_channel")
        extra_kwargs = {"password": {"write_only": True, }}


class TwitchChannelSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    class Meta:
        model = TwitchChannel
        fields = (
            'user_id',
            'login',
            'display_name',
            'email',
            'profile_image_url',
            'access_token',
            'refresh_token',
            'live',
            'channel_data',
            'created',
            'user'
        )
```

However, when I do a request for the user the field isn't even included at all.

```
  {
    "id": 3,
    "first_name": "Patrick",
    "last_name": "Hanford",
    "email": "testing@streambeacon.tv"
  }
```

I get no error, but the field is non-existent.

Comment: Since it's a reverse relationship, you need to specify 'twitch_channel_set' in the fields of the UserSerializer, instead of just 'twitch_channel'

Comment: `twitch_channel_set` as source keyword produces the same result, making the field `twitch_channel_set` results in `The field 'twitch_channel' was declared on serializer UserSerializer, but has not been included in the 'fields' option.`

Comment: Youu can try to set related_name="twitch_channels" on the user field in the TwitchChannel model. Then in your User serializer you would use "twitch_channels" both when you declare it's serializer and in the fields list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`source`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) argument to specify model's field name. By default django use `modelname_set` name for reverse foreign key relation, so you can use this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    twitch_channel = TwitchChannelSerializer(read_only=True, many=True, source="twitchchannel_set")
```

Also you need to use `ModelSerializer` for both classes:

```
class TwitchChannelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
```

Comment: Ah this was my original solution, but I had `twitch_channel_set` which wasn't working. This does display the field now, but it shows as empty `{}`. Any ideas there?

Comment: @CodeSpent ah, you should use `ModelSerializer` for ChannelSerializer also.

Comment: Yupp that was it, I forgot it was ModelSerializer. Getting some other weird errors, but believe this is resolved, thanks!